# In the javascript, is this function pure

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

```
function add() {
    var args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var fn = function() {
        var fn_args = [].slice.call(arguments)
        return add.apply(null, args.concat(fn_args))
    }
    fn.toString = function() {
        return '' + args.reduce(function(acc, prev){
            return acc + prev
        })
    }
    return fn;
}
```

I don't sure if this function is pure.

because I can change the result externally;

```
var result = add(1);
result.toString = () => 'hello';
```

Comment: 1. is your function result predictable, i.e. is your return value always the same? 2. has it got any side effects? If those two points are true for your function in JavaScript or any other langage, then it is "pure".

Comment: It's not clear to me why you think that last snippet tells us anything about the purity of the function.

Comment: It's referentially transparent. The fact that your implementation involves mutating local state does not impact this property. However, the implementation is not pure. That said, since you cannot create a function and define a method on it in a single expression, you have no choice so don't worry about it. Regarding mutation of the result, @jonsharp is right, it's unrelated to purity. However, you can make the result immutable very easily if you so desire.

Comment: This code comes from chatting with a friend，But some people say it's a pure function, some people say it's not a pure function.
Those who think it is an impure function use the Wikipedia description ：
(no variation with local static variables)
to explain： the toString is a local static variable, and the result will be able to change externally. 
And I don't sure if this function is pure...

Comment: @jonrsharpe emmm... In <JavaScript functional programing> book, " cannot rely on data that has been changed by external operations" is a property of pure function. But in the last snippet we can change the toString externally to change the result.

Comment: But that doesn't change what the function itself returns. Next time you call `add(1)` (or `add(anything)`, for that matter) it doesn't return something whose `toString` returns `"hello"`, does it? There are things you *could* change that would alter all further returns from the function, like the definitions of the methods you're calling on arrays, but to that extent JavaScript itself is fundamentally impure.

Comment: The function itself is pure. That the result is a mutable (function) object does not matter. The onus is on the caller not to mutate an object that they don't own.

Comment: @Bergi  Thank you very much for your answer. I understand